# display html file in a textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea in a form that will eventually be an email form. Using Jquery I have loaded a signature file and want to display it in the text area. I have the file but using .html displays nothing and using val(data) produces the code on my box . Can anyone offer any help please

```
    function loadedData(data) {
$('#mail_body').val(data)

}

$.get('../signature/sig1.htm', loadedData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put html in a textarea. But you can parse it with jQuery before putting it there.

```
function loadedData(data) {
   var sig = $("#mysig", data);
   $('#mail_body').val(sig);

}

$.get('../signature/sig1.htm', loadedData);
```

Or you should use some wysiwyg to add HTML capabilities to your edit box:

http://ckeditor.com/

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` elements are not rich-text editors. They can only display plain text. To have a WYSIWYG editor, try [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).